# Microsoft Word Print/Save as PDF now “Untitled” instead of DOCX filename

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, pdf, printing, filenames

Just recently my copy of Microsoft Word for Mac Version 16.72 (2021) has stopped titling filenames of PDFs when exported from the Print dialog.

Steps:

- Open or create a Word DOCX file.
- Hit <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, or click File, Print…
- Click PDF, or click downward arrow, Save as PDF…

Expected/previous behavior:

- File system dialog appears with the prepared PDF filename the same as the DOCX filename.

Observed/new behavior:

- File system dialog appears with the prepared PDF filename “Untitled”.

Anyone know why this changed, how I can change it back?

Comment: BTW, I note that on a Windows OS PC, printing from Firefox using the browser's *internal Print to PDF* does correctly name files (with option to change name), but selecting the *external Print to PDF* (i.e., Windows) option leaves the filename field blank. Yes, that does not help at all with your issue, just confirms that MS has made this feature a bit less convenient. If you enter the first characters of an existing file, such as the Word DOCX file, the whole filename *can* be selected, though.

Comment: Same thing just happened on windows 10. Presumably as a result of some update and an idiotic decision by some MS program manager. Others reported it months ago on Windows, not sure why the difference in time between them and me,.